# Asynchronous DB update in JBoss 5.1

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, jboss, queue

My application consists of a suite of web services running in JBOSS 5.1 (Java 6, Spring 3.1). The web service code calls a DAO function to update the DB and, for performance reasons, I'd like to make that call asynchronous (the update is not important to the web service response). What are my options here?

The consensus seems to be to avoid managing threads myself and let the app server do it. What are my options in JBOSS 5.1 (Java 6, Spring 3.1)? Some kind of JMS solution? Or using JBOSS ThreadPool? Or MDBs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JMS (MDB being the easiest way to do it) certainly works and I would recommend doing that when you're using a Java EE platform below Java EE 6, especially because you immediately have queuing support to be able to throttle execution should that be neccessary. Plus JMS keeps working no matter which version of Java EE you target.

I've also abused the EJB timer service for asynchronous invocation of an EJB method, but that is very ugly.

Comment: JMS is an excellent choice, albeit a bit heavy weight if you just want to dump stuff into the DB (for logging etc.). If it is logging, you might want to look into DB appenders of your logging framework (like log4j).

Answer (score 0):

In case theres no support for asynchronous tasks in JBoss, you can just setup a spring thread pool to handle your DAO calls.

Example

```
    <bean id="myExecutioner" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
      <property name="corePoolSize" value="${executor.ws.poolsize}"/>
      <property name="maxPoolSize" value="${executor.ws.poolsize}"/>
      <property name="keepAliveSeconds" value="120"/>
      <property name="threadNamePrefix" value="WsExecTask-"/>
      <property name="allowCoreThreadTimeOut" value="true"/>        
      <property name="rejectedExecutionHandler" value="#{new java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$CallerRunsPolicy()}"/>
   </bean>
```

Then in your webservice just wire the Executor defined above and pass a Runnable object wraping your DAO call to the execute() method.

Make sure to read the ThreadPoolTaskExecutor description and understand the reject handler part if you decide to go with this solution.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this. You'll either have to manage your database connections outside the container, or mess with the container's persistent management, which could be hacky and frustrating